# What is the difference between generic type constraint method and method with generic parameter

Tags: c#, interface, icomparable

Hi I would like to ask what is the difference and what are the benefits of one approach and the another when considering generic type constraint method and method with generic parameter. For example:

```
public int Foo(IComparable[] array)
{
}

public int Foo<T>(T[] array) where T : IComparable
{
}
```

Comment: array are super special... Try it with `List` and you'll see the difference.